# any way to discover nearby wireless devices not in same network - Android / IOS?

Tags: android, ios, networking, discovery, service-discovery

I want to be able to discover any kind of devices nearby (10 m) and possibly retrieve some device information about them in addition to the MAC address. This should be discovered through WIFI.

The devices doesn't need to be in the same network (as most questions asking for similar behaviour), they can just be passing next to this "antena".

Devices constantly communicate to nearby access-points so I thought that an app would be able to catch these broadcasts too.

I was trying to use Android Nsd (Network Service Discovery) until I found this only works for devices in the same network. I just began to research on bonjour.

Another possibility: could device connect to nearby access point to get this info?

Comment: I know if you are using bluetooth, you can connect to "unpaired" devices as well. Then after this connection you could send commands to retrieve more information about the device. Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices

Comment: I only suggested bluetooth as a 10m range is with its capabilities.

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest thank you, but the requirement preference is to be done via wifi, bluetooth gives similar information but most people have it turned off until they actually need it. I will review the documentation though to see how much info I can get from impaired devices.

Comment: You cannot do this on iOS as it would require low-level access to the Wi-Fi radio in order to "sniff" the wireless network packets.

It may be possible on Android through the development of custom firmware

Answer (score 0):

How about *Nearby Connections*? I think it exactly matches your use case.

It uses a combination of Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, and inaudible sound (using the device’s speaker and microphone) to establish proximity.

https://developers.google.com/nearby

Comment: Thank you, but I believe that this service needs both devices to be willing to find each other. The project need is to discover any device; and that device doesn't need any special app or implementation.

Comment: @zsolt-safrany have you tried to make Google Nearby work with both iOS and Android devices? Did you succeed?